# Is this theoretical encryption device secure?

Tags: one-time-pad

I'm trying to design an encryption and decryption device that is extremely secure, but simple in design so that it can be understood and audited.

Here is my attempt, do you see any vulnerabilities?

The device consists of a keyboard, 2 LCD character displays, a SD card reader, and 3 arduinos:

[image: system diagram]

- The SD card has no file system and is full of one time pads. The pads are labeled with a short random number.
- Each SD card has 2 sets of pads. One for person A and one for person B. Person A transmits with A pads, and decodes with B pads, and vice-versa.
- The SD card is connected to the "core" arduino. This arduino takes in characters from the "secret" serial port and encrypts them with a one time pad. It then sends them to the public serial port. This arduino uses no complicated code and no libraries. It must be as simple and understandable as possible.
- Surrounding this are 2 other arduinos. One for the secret side, and one for the public side.
- The secret arduino has a LCD and the keyboard and is used to compose messages. It has no wireless or other communication capabilities. It can use libraries and other things like that that are less trusted.
- The public arduino just drives a LCD to display the encrypted message.
- 2 LCDs are used so that it can be easily verified that there is no communication between the secret and public sides (besides through the core).
- Connections would be made in such a way that the core cannot be programmed by any of the other arduinos using it's bootloader.
- A separate device generates pairs of SD cards. Lets assume for now that the resulting pads are perfectly random and secret (I'll make that a separate question).

**Usage:**

- A pair of SD cards are generated containing identical one time pads. SD cards are exchanged in person.
- A message is typed by the sender into the secure side. They press a certain key and the secret arduino transmits the message to the core. The secret arduino appends a hash of a few bytes to the message using a hashing library.
- The core encrypts the message, and prepends the pad number. The core then transmits this to the public arduino. The pad is then deleted and overwritten several times.
- The public arduino displays the message.
- The encrypted message is relayed to the recipient.
- The recipient has an identical SD card full of one time pads.
- He types the message into the secret side of his device and presses the decrypt key.
- The message is transmitted to the core. The core decrypts it, and transmits it back to the secret side to be displayed. The core then deletes and overwrites the one time pad.

**Known limitations:**

- Users must exchange keys in person.
- If the location of the device is known (like at an embassy), it may be possible to deduce the message through EM emissions.
- If a device is captured, it may be possible to recover some keys that were deleted.
- If a device is captured, the owner can be impersonated.

**Logic:**

- The parts are generic, and not encryption related, and can be bought anywhere. That makes the device hard to backdoor. Unlike say, a kit, which could easily have chips which aren't what they claim to be.
- The core software is distributed as a text file, so it's hard to hide malicious functionality.
- The arduinos have limited power and memory, so there's not a lot of room to hide malicious code "from the factory".
- Using multiple arduinos reduces the amount of code that must be highly trusted, and creates an obvious divide between secure and insecure domains.
- The public and secret arduino code can be easily modified with libraries to support different LCDs, keyboards, etc, with low risk of compromising security.
- Pad distribution is not that big of a deal in the modern day. One SD card of pads could last years. How often is it necessary to communicate securely with someone who we've never met? And in that case, how would you even know who you're communicating with?
- PC based tools can never be fully trusted. There's too much code and attack surface on a PC for any non-government sized person or group to understand and audit.

Comment: The length of the original message is not hidden, which is a security issue if the message is YES or NO, or a name. It seems electronically possible for the public side to eavesdrop on the secret side thru the shared GND and power supply rails, so public side must be trusted too. So why 3 devices? Treatment of errors is not described, and can be a practical security issue (e.g. errors in transmission, what happens if the hash does not check, retry procedures where the devil may lie). And, this is disputably [on-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Good points. Power rail snooping could be mitigated fairly easily by using separate power supplies for each arduino. Just separate wall warts, or batteries. There would be no error checking.

Comment: DannyNiu, kelalaka, Daniel S. decided to close you down. I apologise on their behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent idea Drew :-) Some observations then...

1. I don't think that files can be easily verified as deleted on an SD card.  `delete("filename")` certainly doesn't work. You'll have to delve into this. Full SD card erasure can be guaranteed with the blowtorch and brick technique. (If you can afford all this kit, you can afford a cheapo blowtorch. Find brick as necessary.)
2. Owner impersonation can be easily mitigated through the use of a HMAC rather than just a hash.  Don't use *"a few bytes"*. Use 32 bytes from something like SHA256 which is available on this platform.
3. You will need a truly random 128+ bit salt for the HMAC algorithm.  This is going to be a little problem.  You will need additional 'features' on the secret Arduino to create this as that platform does not include a TRNG. And please don't just read a floating input pin with the ADC.
4. And please don't pre-create the salts using the *"separate device"*.  They have to be created at use time. And then transmitted as part of the exchanged message.
5. And then you're both going to have to generate a key.  On a PC we'd use something like Argon2x, but you'll have limited options for a memory hard KDF with only 2kB of RAM.  Hmm. You may have to compromise and use a simpler (easier to crack) mechanism.
6. The above is a good security reason for migrating to a PC platform.
7. Label the pads with at least truly random 128/256 bit filenames so that they never repeat/collide. This allows for simultaneous transmission to multiple recipients in a star topology.
8. Make all pads exactly the same length (say $n$ Tweets) and use it all up for messages of shorter length. One message = one pad. That will mask the plain text length.
9. I suggest that @fgrieu 's comment regarding re-transmission is not important here. I suggest you adopt the WW2 approach to errors in transmission and just ignore the broken message.  Just as if a mistake was made with a paper & pigeon OTP.  It will vastly eliminate potential devilry and just requires some discipline.
10. An interesting extension becomes possible if you're using a platform with GPIO/UART.  You can achieve limited distance wireless transmission through all sorts of kit from Bluetooth, through LoRaWAN to walkie-talkies/CB/Ham.
11. I also suggest that precautions against TEMPEST attack are not feasible for lowly people like us. That's an app too far...

Keep soldering!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into HMAC. The thing is, it would have to run on the secret side due to the complexity, and that code isn't fully trusted. Including it might give the user a false sense of security.

Comment: I fully agree on other points except 6 and 10. The best algorithms written by geniuses are no good if you have a simple trojan on your machine. And hiding something like that is not very difficult. I didn't include number 10 intentionally. I think it's really important for security that the user is in the loop. That way if things start getting weird, they may notice. For example, hashes failing, messages the wrong length, etc.

Comment: @Drew HMAC is just a few regular hashes with say SHA256.  You can validate a SHA algorithm by using public test vectors.  The important thing is that it will give you two factor authentication that can stop the Man impersonating you, and I think that benefit trumps the tiny risk of bad hashes.