# What is the simplest method of protecting a one time pad encrypted message from bit flip attacks?

Tags: hmac, mac, one-time-pad

I'm building a micro-controller based encryption device that uses one time pads. [System details](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/110884/is-this-theoretical-encryption-device-secure)

The reason I'm going this route is that I want a system which secure, but also very simple and easy to understand.

One time pad encryption has a known vulnerability against bit flip attacks. I would like to mitigate this risk by adding an authentication code to each message.

But the trouble is finding an algorithm that doesn't rely on complicated hashes or other fancy math. Does such an algorithm exist?

An algorithm that is provably unbreakable like OTP would be ideal.

There are some factors that might make this easier:

- It doesn't have to be efficient. Even if it doubles the message and pad size that is acceptable.
- "Infinite" perfect secret/random numbers are available from the pad storage.
- The messages are short (200 characters max), and a human is in the loop, so brute force attacks are not possible. There is no error checking or automatic re-transmission that might hide failed brute force attempts.
- Following from the above, even if an attacker can randomly succeed in bit flipping a message that is acceptable. As long as the odds are very low (lets say 1 in 10 million) and it can't be reduced.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=one+time+pad+integrity Your answer in one of those!

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks, I've read almost all of those, but not all of them. That paper on one time mac xor hashing sounds like it could be perfect. Will read up on it.

Comment: Any pairwise independent function works an information theoretically secure MAC. E.g. a linear polynomial over the field

Comment: One time macs are dandy, but unfortunately this forum only seems to have theoretic/mathematical descriptions of how they work. I've not seen a single implementation example /code that doesn't require a PhD in mathematics & bodgery. So certainly for me, they're out of reach :-(

Comment: Also recall from our last conversation, unless you incorporate a secret (only in your head) password, your scheme is still vulnerable to impersonation.

Comment: @PaulUszak Thanks, but I'm just trying to tackle one issue at a time.